# Apple DEP: Define profile API. What is an url in request body?

Tags: ios, mdm

I'm looking to define an Apple Device Enrollment Program (DEP) profile. I followed the Apple documentation [MDM-Protocol-Reference](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf) and made a successful API call to create the profile. However, an **"invalid profile"** error is triggered when a device attempts to configure/install the profile.

During profile creation, there's a body parameter called `url`, As per my understanding I'm passing the URL of the MDM enrollment profile as its value. If I open that URL in a browser, it triggers the download of a .mobileconfig file.

[Here is a screenshot of Define profile request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YFet.png)

Can someone help me with what should be the correct value for `url` key